# Replacing JCenter() with mavenCentral() causes error in webrtc

Tags: android, webrtc

Could not find `org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006`. Required by: project `:app`

Comment: Possible workaround: Do you need to replace JCenter for this library? JCenter now isn't shutting down, rather it's becoming read-only "indefinitely".

Answer (score 5):

Although I tend to agree re-adding `jcenter` repo, due to that annoying lint warning using deprecated repo I'd like to suggest a different solution.

1. Go to jcenter and download the aar/jar file of dependency `org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006`.
2. Check the pom file if inner dependencies are needed and add them to project (normally if they exist in maven central, manually download aar/jar otherwise).
3. Copy aar/jar of your dependency (and inner dependencies, if needed) it to your project's `libs` folder.
4. Add dependency to all files in `libs` folder.

I'll update this answer with code samples as soon as I'm able.

## EDIT:

Download AAR file from the following link and save it in `libs` folder:
http://estigia.lsi.us.es:1681/artifactory/libs-release/org/webrtc/google-webrtc/1.0.32006/

Add this dependency to compile all files in `libs` folder:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar"])
```

I don't see any inner dependencies in the POM file so I think it should work.

## EDIT #2:

It appears that they deliberately removed this option because of all sort of errors.

In the [JetBrains ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274929#focus=Comments-27-5128965.0-0)'s comment they offer to create a local maven repo and use it:

> Discussed with the Android Studio team. This option was deliberately removed, because of technical problems it introduces which often results in broken packages. Proper way to have local AAR dependency is local maven repository. E.g.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file://${projectDir}/repo"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing you only need to copy all of the artifacts from good old jcenter with the original file structure and naming convention.

Comment: thanks @Shlomi Katriel will try this and waiting for your code samples.

Comment: Thank you, in my case, it worked, but the command Rebuild Project causes an error: Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error).

And the newest version of Android Studio removed wrapper for aar:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274929

Comment: In the mentioned issue they offered a workaround - creating a local maven repository within the project dir. once created, you can just copy all of the artifacts from the old jcenter. Example inside.